# WooCommerce/Elementor Pagination Changing The Entire Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I'm using the WooCommerce Plugin for wordpress. I'm calling multiple product queries on the same page (books, templates, etc).

I'm using Elementor as a page builder, using the WooCommerce features within Elementor.

When I change the pagination to the second page on "books", it will reload the entire page and change all of the products to the second page.

Looking to change just one of the pages.

Comment: How are you calling multiple product queries? Please post the code.

Comment: I just edited my question - hope that will help. Thank you!

Comment: It seems to change the entire page when I hit the number 2,3,4 etc.

Comment: What is the code you're using?  Nobody can help you without it.